# Using Java to assert first item in a List<>

Tags: java, list, selenium

For practice, I'm using Selenium (java) to create a test search google for the term "Selenium" and assert that the first result at the top of the results page is for SeleniumHQ.

It's been many years since I've used Java, and I'm having a hard time remembering how to iterate through the list and assert the first object in the list.

```
public class SeleniumTest {

    private static String baseURL = "http://google.com";
    private static String searchTerm = "Selenium";
    private static String seleniumResultString = "Selenium - Web Browser Automation";
    private static String googleSearchBarLocatorById = "lst-ib";
    private static String googleResultLocatorByClassName = "r";


    public void driverProperties() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/<<user>>/Downloads/chromedriver");

    }

    private void searchGoogleForSelenium() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get(baseURL);
        ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById(googleSearchBarLocatorById).sendKeys(searchTerm);
        ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById(googleSearchBarLocatorById).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    }

    private void returnGoogleResults() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        List<WebElement> resultTitles = new ArrayList<>(((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementsByClassName(googleResultLocatorByClassName));
        if (resultTitles.get(0).equals(seleniumResultString)) {
            System.out.println(seleniumResultString + " is the first result!");
            driver.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println(seleniumResultString + " is not the first result!");
            driver.close();
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void seleniumResultsTest() {
        driverProperties();
        searchGoogleForSelenium();
        returnGoogleResults();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at com.slg.selenium.SeleniumTest.returnGoogleResults(SeleniumTest.java:36)
    at com.slg.selenium.SeleniumTest.seleniumResultsTest(SeleniumTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Hoping someone can help identify my error here. Many thanks for any and all help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
List<WebElement> resultTitles = new ArrayList<>(((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementsByClassName(googleResultLocatorByClassName));
```

can produce a list of size 0 and when you are trying to get the first element of an empty list you are getting `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`. That's why add:

```
if (resultTitles.size() > 0)
```

or as @AndyTurner already mentioned:

```
if (!resultTitles.isEmpty())
```

Replace:

```
private void returnGoogleResults() {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        List<WebElement> resultTitles = new ArrayList<>(((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementsByClassName(googleResultLocatorByClassName));
        if (resultTitles.get(0).equals(seleniumResultString)) {
            System.out.println(seleniumResultString + " is the first result!");
            driver.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println(seleniumResultString + " is not the first result!");
            driver.close();
        }

    }
```

with:

```
private void returnGoogleResults() {
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  List<WebElement> resultTitles = new ArrayList<>(((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementsByClassName(googleResultLocatorByClassName));
  if (!resultTitles.isEmpty() && resultTitles.get(0).equals(seleniumResultString)) {
    System.out.println(seleniumResultString + " is the first result!");
    driver.close();
  } else {
    System.out.println(seleniumResultString + " is not the first result!");
    driver.close();
  }

}
```

PS:

```
List<WebElement> resultTitles = new ArrayList<>(((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementsByClassName(googleResultLocatorByClassName));
```

can be simplified like this:

```
List<WebElement> resultTitles = driver.findElementsByClassName(googleResultLocatorByClassName));
```

And:

```
private void searchGoogleForSelenium() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseURL);
    ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById(googleSearchBarLocatorById).sendKeys(searchTerm);
    ((ChromeDriver) driver).findElementById(googleSearchBarLocatorById).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
private void searchGoogleForSelenium() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get(baseURL);
    driver.findElementById(googleSearchBarLocatorById).sendKeys(searchTerm);
    driver.findElementById(googleSearchBarLocatorById).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
}
```

Comment: Or, (perhaps) more idiomatically: `if (!resultTitles.isEmpty())`

Comment: @AndyTurner I think your suggestion is better than my. I have added it to my answer. Hopefully it is ok?

Comment: RADICAL! THANK YOU!! :)